# When I run mocha tests I always get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I'm trying to run my app tests with mocha and supertest but I always get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

app.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  config = require('./config/config');

mongoose.connect(config.db);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function () {
  throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + config.db);
});

var modelsPath = __dirname + '/app/models';
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
  if (file.indexOf('.js') >= 0) {
    require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
  }
});

var app = express();

require('./config/express')(app, config);
require('./config/routes')(app);

app.listen(config.port);

exports.app = app;
console.log('LISTEN ON http://localhost:3000/')
```

test.js code:

```
var should = require('should'); 
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('../../../app').app;

describe('Categories', function() {
    it('- POST is testing', function(done) {
        request(app)
        .post('http://localhost:3000/categories')
        .send({title:'test', text:'test'})
        .end(function(e, res) {
            console.log(e, res);
        });
    });
});
```

Test output:

```
LISTEN ON http://localhost:3000/


  Categories
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' } undefined
    1) - POST is testing


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

Done, but with warnings.
```

Could you give any clue why this happend?

Thank you in advance!

Topicus

Comment: "connection refused" usually means you're using the wrong port, or your server isn't running or not bound to that ip:port.

Comment: Update please `var request = require('supertest');` – what is your `supertest` file?

Answer (score 46):

The problem was the path. Replacing "localhost:3000/categories" by this "/categories" all works fine.

Working example:

```
describe('Categories', function() {
    it('- POST is testing', function(done) {
        request(app)
        .post('/categories')
        .send({title:'test', text:'test'})
        .end(function(e, res) {
            console.log(e, res);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had the same prob.  My questions is: why?  Should be the same difference.

Comment: @Topicus i spent hours behind this! .. finally works! :thumbsup:

Comment: spent like an hour! I didn't have the forward slash at the beginning of the path

Comment: @landrykapela The same thing just happened to me. I had 5 test cases, 4 were working, 1 was failing with connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80. It took me two days to realize that all four other test cases had a forward slash as a prefix to begin the path, and for the failing one, I'd forgotten the prefix.

Comment: Man you're a genius. How did you come up with this.

Answer (score 13):

I'm facing same problem, and find out the problem is- only the path url. Path should be in this way -

```
.post('/categories')
```